# How to check a dates of a date range lies in between two dates in mysql query

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have a date range like

date from=2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20

if I have another date ranges

like

```
- 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15
- 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-21
- 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-21
- 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19
- 2011-10-21 - 2011-10-26
```

I want  sql query which shows only the date range whose dates lies in between above `(2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20)` date range.

Here only `2011-10-21 - 2011-10-26` does not lies in `date from=2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20`

Result must show

```
- 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15
- 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-21
- 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-21
- 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19
```

these dates

Hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: First of all, what data type are you using? `Datetime`? And you say you want between AND above 14th and 20th. So in all essence you really want > 14th?

Comment: another date ranges - what is it? do they keep in some table or they are provided by user input?

Comment: How are these ranges stored in your database? Each in a separate column as a DATE field? Or string in a single column? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ancide yes Datetime ..... checks if the DATES(2011-10-11,2011-10-12,2011-10-13,2011-10-14,2011-10-15) for 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15
lies between **date from=2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
date_from < '2011-10-20' AND date_to > '2011-10-14'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM datetable where mydate BETWEEN '2011-10-14' AND '2011-10-20';
```

Note : if you are using only datatype = date

Comment: mydate is in range ie 
2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15, 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-21, 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-21, 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19 and checks if dates for eg 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19 (2011-10-16,2011-10-17,2011-10-18,2011-10-19) lies in date from=2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE date_from >= '2011-10-14' AND date_to <= '2011-10-20'`?

But this will only work if you have your column's data type set to `DATE` or `DATETIME`

Comment: Does not works for 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15
2011-10-11 - 2011-10-21
 these dates

Answer (score 0):

You can go and search on the Internet :-)

The first links you will come across is this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/692/

Hope the above link helps in resolving your query.

Or, you could give something like this:

SELECT * FROM `myTBL` WHERE myReqDate NOT BETWEEN '2011-10-14' AND '2011-10-20'

Comment: myReqDate is in range ie 2011-10-11 - 2011-10-15
2011-10-11 - 2011-10-21
2011-10-15 - 2011-10-21
2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19
and checks if dates like for eg 2011-10-15 - 2011-10-19 (2011-10-16,2011-10-17,2011-10-18,2011-10-19) lies in *date from=2011-10-14 & date to=2011-10-20*