# how to select date range by specified year-month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in mysql server database called `mytbl`. There is a date column `prod_date` that contains all the date in year 2019 in the format `2019-xx-xx`.

I need to extract all rows that from `Jan 2019 to May 2019`.  My following code is not returning anything.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytbl
WHERE prod_date BETWEEN CONCAT('2019', '-', '01') AND CONCAT('2019', '-', '05')
```

Can someone tell what I did wrong? How I can select the date from by year and month only?

Thanks a lot in  advance.

Comment: I think this solution will help you. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304504/how-to-check-a-dates-of-a-date-range-lies-in-between-two-dates-in-mysql-query

Comment: Is your column _date_ or some type of _datetime_?  The answer to this matters here.

Answer (score 1):

This should just give you the result.

```
SELECT * from mytbl WHERE Year(prod_date) = 2019 and Month(prod_date) BETWEEN 1 and 5
```

Comment: This works, but kills any chance of using an index which includes the `prod_date` column.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `concat()` just do :

```
where prod_date >= '2019-01-01' and prod_date <= '2019-05-31'
```

This assumes prod_date has `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows between two dates like if your date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. If you have the other formats, you can change the formats and query.

```
SELECT `mytbl`.* FROM `mytbl` where `prod_date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an inequality:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytbl
WHERE prod_date >= '2019-01-01' AND prod_date < '2019-06-01';
```

For a small explanation, the right condition restricts to dates strictly *less* than midnight of June 1, 2019, which includes all of May of the same year.  Note that writing the `WHERE` clause this was is *sargable*, meaning that an index using the `prod_date` might be usable.

Comment: @Ishan No, not easily, you can't.  You can't, because a date, without a time component, defaults to meaning _midnight_ of that day.  The upvoter of your comment also does not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution but an edit for your query.

```
SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE prod_date BETWEEN CONCAT('2019','-','01','-','01') AND CONCAT('2019','-','06','-','01')
```

Comment: In addition to not being sargable and also using several expensive (and unnecessary) concatenation operations, your logic is wrong, because it includes midnight of June 1st.  Think that doesn't matter?  Don't write code like this if you plan on working for an accounting firm.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-assuming you are using SQL SERVER you can use  :
SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE datepart(year,prod_date)='2019' and datepart(month,prod_date) in (01,02,03,04,05)